# Couchbase iterate on properties and get value

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase document like :

```
{
  "data": {
    "author1": {
      "title": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    },
    "author2": {
      "title": [
        "3",
        "4"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And I would like to get with a N1QL request :

```
1
2
3
4
```

How is it possible ?

Comment: Is it always author1 and author2, or will the number of authors vary (e.g. author3, author4 in some documents)?

Comment: yes it can vary, for example author-3, author-abc and some on. And I can have multiple authors, not only 2.

Comment: Oh, so it's not even a regular naming convention? it could be "author1" followed by "author-2" and then "author-A", for instance? Do they at least always start with "author"?

Comment: Yes they will always begin with a pattern like author

Answer (score 1):

This might work. It assumes that `title` contains the values you want.

```
select VALUE ARRAY_FLATTEN(OBJECT_VALUES(OBJECT_UNWRAP(b))[*].title,1)
from books b
```

- [`OBJECT_UNWRAP`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html#object_unwrapexpression) gets rid of the `data` and unwraps to peel away a layer.
- [`OBJECT_VALUES`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html#object_valuesexpression) then returns the values of the individual fields (whatever  they are: author1, authorA, author-123)
- The `[*].title` syntax returns every `title` field in the resulting array
- [`ARRAY_FLATTEN`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-flatten) combines the arrays
- Finally, use [`VALUE`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/3_query.html#Select_element) to get the raw values.

I am NOT claiming this is the best approach, but it seems to work okay with the small sample data set (of 2 docs) that I created based on your question.

Comment: Yes thank you it works ! 
But if I have : { data : {.....}, date : "" }
I think it will change the request because OBJECT_UNWRAP will not work

Comment: You're right. But I'd recommend checking out the OBJECT_ and ARRAY_ functions and even dig into the SELECT syntax; you might be able to find a combination that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY v.title FOR n:v IN b.data END,1) AS title
FROM books b;
```

OR

```
SELECT ARRAY_FLATTEN(OBJECT_VALUES(b.data)[*].title,1) AS title
FROM books b;
```

If need across the documents

```
WITH books AS ([ { "data": { "author1": { "title": [ "1", "2" ] }, "author2": { "title": [ "3", "4" ] } } },
                { "data": { "author1": { "title": [ "1", "5" ] }, "author2": { "title": [ "6", "1" ] } } }
              ])
SELECT DISTINCT RAW t
FROM books AS b
UNNEST ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY v.title FOR n:v IN b.data END,1) AS t;
```

FOR n:v IN b.data

```
Looping construct

If b.data is OBJECT n holds field name, v holds value
If b.data is ARRAY  n holds position, v holds value
```